# Call a Spring Controller from another one

Tags: java, spring, controller

I have the URLs `/users` and `/users/58` which are handled by UserController.
Now, I want to redirect `/users/58/images` to ImageController in order to move all code concerning Images to ImageController.

Here is what UserController looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/users")
List<User> paginate() { ... }

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/users/{id}")
List<User> get(Long id) { ... }

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/users/{id}/images")
List<Image> images(Long userId) {
    // What I want to do is something like this
    ImageController images = new ImageController();
    return images.getByUser(userId);
}
```

First, is that a good design? If yep, how can I call another controller from a controller?

Comment: I believe you can simply define another controller with proper mapping. Spring should use the most specific request mapping that matches your URI.

Comment: what you need is a service not another controller or a repository.

Comment: ..is `ImageController` already "in place" ..and (if,) to what request path is it mapped?

Comment: @xerx593, no, nothing is implemented yet. I'm just trying to design all of this first.

Comment: @efekctive, Is it a good design to call `imageService.getByUsers(userId)` in the `UserController` class? Or should I do `userService.getImages(id)`?

Comment: Are the images in a db? By your code snippet the methods look like repos but you are calling it a controller.

Comment: Yes, images are in database.. I think `imageService.getByUsers(userId)` is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Then create a repository. You do not need a controller or another url to achieve that.

Comment: The second and third methods do not make any sense. Change them. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can't call another controller from controller, because Front Controller (Dispatcher Servlet) is orchestrating all requests. Based on your URI request will be handler over by matching Controller/Request Handler. So you can redirect with URI from redirecting controller and pick up that URI in redirected controller.Example (handler methods do not have to be in the same controller)

Handler in redirecting controller

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/users/{id}/images")
   public String getUserId() {
      return "redirect:/getUsersPage/{id}";
   }
```

Handler in redirected controller

```
   @Autowired
   ImageService imageService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/getUsersPage/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getUsersPage(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
      return imageService.getByUser(id);;
   }
```

Regarding design : If it is a REST service and there is no front end so your request handler is returning message body, you can inject service (say imageService) and return value obtained from service.